# How to use checkboxes to filter data in angular smart table?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, smart-table

I'm trying to filter data with checkboxes because I just need yes or no options.

```
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <input type="checkbox" data-st-search="option1" checked>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <input type="checkbox" data-st-search="option2" checked>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
         <input type="checkbox" data-st-search="option3" checked>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
         <input type="checkbox" data-st-search="option4" checked>
    </div>
```

It sends just the last one always on

Answer (score 1):

`Laurent` sugest creating a directive to work with checkboxes in [Filtering with a checkbox](https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table/issues/387).
I adapted his approach to my scenario and got the following result:

Html:

```
<div st-pipe="vm.FilterData" st-table="Data">
     <st-checkbox id="IdForClick" text="Text for Label" predicate="ModelName"></st-checkbox>
     <table>
     ...
     </table>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
vm.FilterData= function (tableState) {
     console.log(tableState.search)
     //filter logic
};
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('App').directive('stCheckbox', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            predicate: '@',
            id: '@',
            text: '@'
        },
        replace: 'true',
        require: '^stTable',
        template:
                '<div class="checkbox checkbox-primary checkbox-inline" ng-click="stCheckChange()">' +
                '<input type="checkbox" id="{{id}}" ng-model="sel" ng-checked="sel">' +
                '<label for="{{id}}"> {{text}}</label>' +
                '</div> ',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
            scope.stCheckChange = function () {
                scope.sel = !scope.sel;
                ctrl.search(scope.sel, scope.predicate);
            };
        }
    };
})
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved but not the prettiest solution.

```
<input type="checkbox"
       st-search="option1"
       value="{{modelOption1}}"
       ng-model="modelOption1"
       ng-true-value="true"
       ng-false-value="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a directive with `require: '^stTable'` then, when checkbox model change, use `table.search(value, scope.predicate);`

OR

```
<input type="checkbox" data-st-search="option3" ng-true-value="'YES'" ng-false-value="'NO'" checked>
```